# Raspbian Jessie Lite fail to start on Pi 1 model B (512MB)

Tags: raspbian, jessie-lite

After flashing the SD card, the Pi starts up first time with a message that the partition will be resized, and the Pi will reboot.

Second boot shows the Raspberry Pi logo in the upper left corner, and then nothing happens - no error message, nothing.

The Pi should be ok, it worked with the original SD image, but I couldn't do an `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` because the repositories could not be read (I guess they were too out-dated).

Do I need to do something special? As far as I understand, Jessie should work with Pi 1 model B also.

Comment: Have you tried a different SD card?

Comment: @Nasha No, I only have the same SD card, but it worked with the original image.

Comment: SD cards can wear out so it's a good opportunity to test your PI with another card. Just in case, eliminate possible causes one by one in order.